# Python 2.7 sqlite3 logging

Tags: python-2.7, logging, sqlite, trace

I am looking for how to use the `sqlite3_trace` in Python 2.7 for logging. I couldn't find it. Is it supported in Python 2.7?

If not, is there a way to enable logging in `sqlite3`, such that the log gets written to some file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's built-in `sqlite3` module has no such function.

You'd have to use another driver, such as [APSW](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/execution.html#tracing).